# fetch mongodb data using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

here is my Node.js code
I am fetching data from mongodb.
When i log users it is giving me cursor instead of resuts.
How can i changes to async await to get the result ?

```
  const yesterday = new Date().getDate() - 1;
  const res4 = dbo
    .collection("assessments")
    .find({ last_date: { $gte: yesterday } })
    .toArray(function async(err, results) {
      if (err) throw err;
      for (let i of results) {
        const last_date = i.last_date;
        const gradeRef = assessment.gradeRef;
        const users = dbo.collection("users").find({ gradeRef: gradeRef });
        console.log("users", users);
        const userIds = [];
        for (let user of users) {
          userIds.push(user._id);
        }
        const parents = dbo
          .collection("parents")
          .find({ userRef: { $in: userIds } });
        for (let parent of parents) {
          const number = parent.number.replace("+", "");
          const msg =
            "موعد التقييم الخاص بك غدا. خذ التقييمات بحلول اليوم لتجنب تفويتها.";
          const url = `https://smssmartegypt.com/sms/api/?username=anand@skillza.co&password=yallaskillza123&sendername=skillza%20LLC&mobiles=${number}&message=${msg}`;
          var request = require("request");
          request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
              console.log(body);
            }
          });
        }
      }
      db.close();
    });
});
```

Please take a look how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.toArray()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/):

```
const users = dbo.collection("users").find({ gradeRef: gradeRef }).toArray();
```